# How to customize mui daterange with styled components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

Is it possible to customize mui daterange with styled components? I tried to grab styles from chrome dev tools and changed them, but nothing happened.Any ideas?

[Image with daterange classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5RKw.png)

```html
const DesktopDateRangePickerStyled = styled(DesktopDateRangePicker)`
  &&& {
    .css-1t8l2tu-MuiInputBase-input-MuiOutlinedInput-input {
      color: green !important;
    }

    .MuiInputBase-input-MuiOutlinedInput-input {
      color: green !important;
    }

    .MuiOutlinedInput-input {
      color: green !important;
    }
    .MuiInputBase-input {
      color: green !important;
    }


     
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can customize the date range picker using styled-components. Unfortunately, it does not look like MUI is providing any CSS API for date range at the moment, but you can still use nested selectors to customize it.

Not sure what your component's structure in HTML looks like, but the input is not part of the `DesktopDateRangePicker` component. You'll have to create a container around all the required date range picker components and then override the CSS classes. Also, you don't need "&&&" in your code. Here is a working example:

[Try it in CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/daterangepicker-material-custom-style-c836d?file=/demo.js)

```html
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import AdapterDateFns from "@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns";
import LocalizationProvider from "@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import DesktopDateRangePicker from "@mui/lab/DesktopDateRangePicker";
import { styled } from "@mui/system";

export default function ResponsiveDateRangePicker() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([null, null]);

  return (
    <DateContainer>
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
        <Stack spacing={3}>
          <DesktopDateRangePicker
            startText="Desktop start"
            value={value}
            onChange={(newValue) => {
              setValue(newValue);
            }}
            renderInput={(startProps, endProps) => (
              <React.Fragment>
                <TextField {...startProps} />
                <Box sx={{ mx: 2 }}> to </Box>
                <TextField {...endProps} />
              </React.Fragment>
            )}
          />
        </Stack>
      </LocalizationProvider>
    </DateContainer>
  );
}

const DateContainer = styled("div")`
  .css-1t8l2tu-MuiInputBase-input-MuiOutlinedInput-input {
    color: red;
  }

  .MuiInputBase-input-MuiOutlinedInput-input {
    color: red;
  }

  .MuiOutlinedInput-input {
    color: red;
  }
  .MuiInputBase-input {
    color: red;
  }
`;
```